# Wordpress Conditional Tags in Theme's function.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to set **HTTP response headers** in my theme's function.php file, whereby i am trying to set expiry time as 6hours for single post page and 20 minutes for others.

I need to check the current accessed url is a single post page. For that i am using wordpress conditional tags and they are not working.

Here is my code:

```
function add_custom_http_headers($headers) {
    $headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public';
    $now = time();
    if(is_single())
        $then = gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", $now + 60*60*6);
    else
        $then = gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", $now + 20*60);

    header("Expires: $then");
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", $now));
    return $headers;
}

add_filter('wp_headers', 'add_custom_http_headers');
```

It seems like we cannot access the conditional tags where i am trying to use them. Please help me with a solution to find the current page type i.e. its a post page / home page / with/without using conditional tags in functions.php or any other suitable point of code to implement this header setting module.

Comment: You mean `is_single()` doesn't work?

Comment: yes it does not work in functions.php as its a part of loading module. So is there any other way to detect page type in wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set headers in your header.php file like this:

```
$now = time();
    if(is_single())
        $then = gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", $now + 60*60*6);
    else
        $then = gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", $now + 20*60);

    header("Expires: $then");
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmstrftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", $now));
    header("Cache-Control: public");
```

Try this, i think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find current page type use `get_post_type()` . the function `is_single()` is not used for checking the post type , it is used to check weather you are on a single post page or not. It returns true when you are on a single post page else false.

Comment: is_single returns true if the current url is a post page ie. what i want to detect and it doesnot work in functions.php, that was my concern.

Comment: Is it returning false then. ?

Comment: Yes it would return false for every page till query var is loaded and functions.php is a part of loading procedure so these variables or functions are not set till then.

Comment: before `is_single()` do this                                                  `$query = new WP_Query ; var_dump($query);` . paste the result here.